# What is this math symbol and its latex representation?

Tags: symbols

[image: The symbol after code]

What symbol is the one after the word "code" above? Is this `\varrho` or just the `@` symbol? How do I pronounce it?

```
\[
\varrho
\]
```

Comment: Welcome! Do not use `$$...$$` in LaTeX. It was deprecated 20+ years ago with the introduction of LaTeX-2e. (It is correct in plain TeX but you are asking about LaTeX.) Use `\[...\]` instead, for example.

Comment: Seems to be a capital C in some calligraphic font, close to Dutch-bcal (but distinct).

Comment: Who is the author of that text? Maybe you could ask them directly.

Comment: Looks a lot like the capital C is the calligraphic Euler fonts. See http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/amsfonts/euscript.pdf But seems also slightly different.

Comment: I would go with `\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}` and `$\mathscr{C}$`...

Comment: @cryingshadow this was a paper "On the Construction of Comma-Free Codes" by William Eastman published in 1965.

Comment: We'd need more context to guess what this means, and thus what symbol that is.

Comment: @vonbrand I provided that in the comments just above yours.

Answer (score 1):

For the context in the given article this is clear a calligraphic version of a captial `C`.  The consensus in the comments is that the closest standard LaTeX equivalent is provided by the `euscript` font:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}

\begin{document}

\( \mathscr{C} \)

\end{document}
```